# 'JSX' is not defined - in .ts file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReItd.png)

Hi there, I have a strange problem.
Any ideas how to handle this?

Here is my linter config:

```
module.exports = {
    env: {
        es6: true,
        browser: true,
        node: true,
    },
    extends: ['airbnb', 'plugin:jest/recommended', 'jest-enzyme', 'plugin:react-hooks/recommended'],
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 12,
        sourceType: 'module',
        ecmaFeatures: {
            jsx: true,
            tsx: true,
            ts: true,
        },
        project: './tsconfig.json',
    },
    settings: {
        'import/resolver': {
            typescript: {},
        },
    },
    globals: {
        JSX: 'readonly',
    },
    plugins: ['babel', 'import', 'jsx-a11y', 'react', 'prettier', '@typescript-eslint', 'react-hooks'],
    rules: {
        'no-use-before-define': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define': ['error'],
        'react-hooks/rules-of-hooks': 'error', // Проверяем правила хуков
        'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 'warn', // Проверяем зависимости эффекта
        'linebreak-style': 'off', // Неправильно работает в Windows.
        'arrow-parens': 'off', // Несовместимо с prettier
        'object-curly-newline': 'off', // Несовместимо с prettier
        'no-mixed-operators': 'off', // Несовместимо с prettier
        'arrow-body-style': 'off', // Это - не наш стиль?
        'function-paren-newline': 'off', // Несовместимо с prettier
        'no-plusplus': 'off',
        'space-before-function-paren': 0, // Несовместимо с prettier
        'intreact/function-component-definition': 0,
        'max-len': ['warn', 180, 2, { ignoreUrls: true, ignorePattern: '^import' }], // airbnb позволяет некоторые пограничные случаи
        'no-console': 'warn', // airbnb использует предупреждение
        'no-alert': 'warn', // airbnb использует предупреждение
        'no-param-reassign': 'off', // Это - не наш стиль?
        radix: 'off', // parseInt, parseFloat и radix выключены. Мне это не нравится.
        camelcase: 'off', // бэк работает с такими_параметрами_запроса_и_ответа
        'react/require-default-props': 'off', // airbnb использует уведомление об ошибке
        'react/forbid-prop-types': 'off', // airbnb использует уведомление об ошибке
        'react/jsx-filename-extension': ['warn', { extensions: ['.js', '.tsx'] }], // airbnb использует .jsx
        'react/jsx-indent': 'off', // конфликт с prettier
        'prefer-destructuring': 'off',
        'react/jsx-indent-props': 'off', // конфликт с prettier
        'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': 'off',
        'react/no-find-dom-node': 'off', // Я этого не знаю
        'react/no-did-mount-set-state': 'off',
        'react/no-unused-prop-types': 'off', // Это всё ещё работает нестабильно
        'no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs': ['warn', 'smart-tabs'],
        'new-cap': 'off',
        'no-shadow': 'off',
        'import/no-unresolved': [2, { ignore: ['@contracts'] }],
        'implicit-arrow-linebreak': 'off',
        'react/jsx-one-expression-per-line': 'off',
        'jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions': 'off',
        'jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events': 'off',
        'import/prefer-default-export': 'off',
        'operator-linebreak': 'off',
        'react/jsx-props-no-spreading': 'off',
        'jsx-quotes': [2, 'prefer-double'],
        'jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid': ['warn', { components: ['Link'], specialLink: ['to'] }],
        'no-unused-vars': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': ['error'],
        'react/sort-comp': [
            1,
            {
                order: ['constructor', 'lifecycle', 'everything-else', 'render'],
            },
        ],
        'import/extensions': [
            'error',
            'ignorePackages',
            {
                js: 'never',
                mjs: 'never',
                jsx: 'never',
                ts: 'never',
                tsx: 'never',
            },
        ],
        'jsx-a11y/label-has-for': [
            2,
            {
                required: {
                    every: ['id'],
                },
            },
        ], // для ошибки вложенных свойств htmlFor элементов label
        indent: 'off',
        'no-tabs': 'off',
        'prettier/prettier': [2, { useTabs: true, endOfLine: 'auto' }],
        'padding-line-between-statements': [
            'warn',
            { blankLine: 'always', prev: 'multiline-const', next: '*' },
            { blankLine: 'always', prev: '*', next: 'multiline-const' },
            { blankLine: 'always', prev: 'const', next: 'const' },
            { blankLine: 'always', prev: ['block-like', 'const'], next: 'return' },
        ],
    },
    overrides: [
        {
            files: ['*.ts', '*.tsx'],
            rules: {
                'no-undef': 0,
            },
        },
    ],
};
```

as u see at the end I tried to add 'override' in .eslintrc.js file - didnt help

and i tried to include `tsconfig.json` file to `eslint` config - catching error that tells i do not include linter config in `tsconfig`, but i did it - nothing changes, error still there. i just thought i will be solution, may be

Comment: What version of React are you on?  In your React import is `JSX` defined?  If you try `React.JSX` explicitly does it change?   If you delete your node_modules and do `npm install` (or whatever is correct for your package manager) does it improve?

Comment: I tried your linter config (removing some of the testing plugins, but leaving at least the react, react-hooks, and import) and wasn't able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @possum i just resolved this problem with reinstalling node_modules and restarting IDE window.